# C# write a line to text file gives System.Char[]

Tags: c#, file, io

When I write a line with File.WriteAllLines, it saves the line I changed into `System.Char[]` instead of the original string

Can someone advise me here? Thanks.

(this code change a character in a text file):

```
int 
 ihl=2,
 ihc=2
 ;

string[]
 asl=//array string lines
  File.
   ReadAllLines
  (
   sdf+sif//file directory and name
  );

string
 slx=//line txt
  asl[ihl];

char[]
 acx=//ary chr txt
  slx.ToCharArray();

acx[ihc]=' ';

asl[ihl]=
 acx.ToString();

string
 snx=//new txt
  new 
   string
    (acx);

Debug.Log
(
    snx
    //asl.ToString()
);

File.
 WriteAllLines
 (
  sdf+sif,//file directory and name
  asl
 );
```

Comment: `asl[ihl] = acx.ToString();` is the problem - you're calling `ToString` on a `char[]`, which doesn't do what you want it to. Create a new string, just like you do with `snx`. As an aside, all the newlines here make the code *much* harder to read. Mind if I reformat it?

Comment: please format your code at least this is very poor code.https://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer

Comment: Thank you Daisy Shipton, it worked out :)

Comment: I'm curious, do you do your coding on a phone in portrait mode?  I've never seen such a vertical coding style before.  It makes it _very_ hard to follow.

Comment: That formatting...why??

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @DaisyShipton, I am adding this as an answer so it is easier for others having the similar issue.

You are creating a `string` from a `char[]`

This line is where the problem is:

```
asl[ihl] = acx.ToString();
```

Change it to be the following where you create a `string` object from your `char[]`

```
asl[ihl] = new string(acx);
```